# App has stops after adding cordova admob plugin in cordova-ionic 1

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, admob

My app name is "Khatavahi".
I have just added "cordova-plugin-admob-free" and now My app stops working.
I am attaching screenshot of it.
If I remove this plugin app working well. 
Can any please help me to figure it out.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: try to remove platforms and add it again

Comment: @ram12393 Hi Ram, removed and added platform again but problem remains same. Thanks for the efforts

Comment: @ParthPatel which ionic version you using V1, V2/ V3 or V4?

Comment: @Sahil using ionic version 1

Comment: @ParthPatel can you share link which plugin you are using?

Comment: @Sahil https://github.com/sunnycupertino/cordova-plugin-admob-simple